# Can one access TestContext in an AssemblyCleanup method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, microsoft-test-manager

In Microsoft's UnitTesting namespace (`Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`) there are `AssemblyInitialize` and `AssemblyCleanup` attributes you can apply to static methods and they will be called before and after all tests respectively.

```
[AssemblyInitialize]
static public void AssemblyInitialize(TestContext testCtx)
{
    // allocate resources
}

[AssemblyCleanup]
static public void AssemblyCleanup()
{
    // free resources
}
```

My question: is it possible and *safe* to access the `TestContext` within `AssemblyCleanup()`?  If not, is storing resource references as static members a reasonable alternative or could that cause problems as well?

Additionally/optionally: what is the reasoning behind *not* passing a reference to the `TestContext` to clean-up methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm accessing a static property on the same class and it seems to be working fine.  I'll update this answer if I encounter any problems.  I am *not*, however, accessing the `TestContext` so I'm curious if that would work too.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass any paramaters to AssemblyCleanup method. Here's the error if you try to do so:

> Result Message:   Method
>   SomeNamespace.TestDatabaseInitializer.AssemblyCleanup has wrong
>   signature. The method must be static, public, does not return a value
>   and should not take any parameter.